# iOS:use the frame constrained by Auto Layout to create a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I create a view called `boundView` using IB and Auto Layout,then in the controller I call `[self.boundView layoutIfNeeded]`,then I pass `self.boundView.frame.size` to a method to generate the size of boundView's subview `CardView`. And then use the

```
 PlayingCardView *playingCardView = [[PlayingCardView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
```

to create subview programmatically. I do use NSLog to check that the size of subview is smaller than superview. But when I use `[self.boundView addSubview:CardView]` to add the subview. It is larger than superview!
Is there something wrong with the coordinate?Or it is because I combine the Auto Layout with the view I create by code?

Comment: you should not combine autolayout with static data

Comment: actually autolayout change frame at runtime... when you will boundView.frame.size then actually you are getting IB's frame of view... not frame which is set by autolayout

Comment: So that means I cannot get the correct frame of the view set by auto layout? I can only set the size using static frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you doing this? If it is in `viewDidLoad` then the autolayout sizes will not have been calculated yet. Try doing it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: I have already tried it, and I also try to call `layoutIfNeeded` in my method.But it still does't work.I think that what @Divyanshu Shama said in comment is right. I always get IB's frame of view which is larger than my `boundView`.So I have to set the frame in code rather than using Auto Layout.

Comment: Well, you will not always get the IB size - that wouldn't make any sense. You just need to do it after the view has been laid out. However, I can't really see if this is in fact your issue without knowing more about your setup. Maybe you could provide more code. Also, tell us exactly where you do stuff, i.e. in what method rather then just saying "in the controller".

Comment: Well,Finally I find the issue.Just as what you said in the answer.I check my code again,and find that I call a method in `viewDidLoad`,and in this method I call `layoutIfNeeded`.As the auto layout size hasn't been calculated, I always get the wrong size.I try to fix it by calling `layoutIfNeeded` in `ViewDidLoad`,but the result is obviously same as above.Just now, I call the my method in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and finally I get the correct frame.Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. And just to clarify for next time: What `layoutIfNeeded` does is to merely force the updating of the layout immediately in stead of waiting for the next update loop cycle. Also, it only has an effect if UIKit sees that the layout actually needs updating (you can tell it this by calling `setNeedsLayout`). In any case, you would still need to get into `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to get the newest frames calculated by the autolayout.

Comment: I get it. I misunderstood `layoutIfNeeded` before. Hopefully, I can continue my work now.